# Finding the convex combination of vertices which yields an inner point of a polytope

Tags: convex-polytopes, geometry, algorithms

Given a convex polytope $P\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and a point $x\in P$, Caratheodory's theorem gives us that there exists a set of at most $n+1$ vertices of $P$, such that $x$ is a convex combination of the elements of this set.

I am interested in figuring out the computational complexity (and algorithm, if available) of finding such a set.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you could find the including set in time proportional to the number of vertices of $P$ times an LP cost, which is unlikely to be adequate for your (or anyone's!) purposes.  Start with $P$, and eliminate redundant vertices one-by-one.  I think each elimination could be done by LP.
(A polynomial-time algorithm for finding a Tverberg partition [related problem] is an open problem.)

Comment: This sounds like a classic question, but I don't know an answer offhand.  However, a simple greedy approach might work: pick a random sample of $n+1$ vertices, see if that works, if not, add more. (Of course this approach is suboptimal), but I guess could be made rigorous.

Comment: Exactly how are you "given" the polytope?!  As a finite set of points (whose convex hull is the polytope), as a finite set of halfspaces (whose intersection is the polytope), or something else?

Comment: Just wondering, are you interested in algorithms that preprocess *P* to use it for many *x*?  


Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hopefully I am using the right notion of convex combination.  The following requires at most n+1 steps, however I do not know how complicated a step is.

Take the given point x and a vertex v visible from x.  Thus the line through v and x passes through the polygon from v to x to a point p on a face or facet on the other side. x should be a convex combination of v and p.  But p is a point interior to a polygon of smaller dimension, and (if I haven't missed my guess) is a convex combination of n or fewer vertices of the polytope. Now induct with p taking the role of x.

I can imagine having to search the vertex space to find v at each stage.  However, coming up with a simplicial decomposition of certain parts of the polytope may speed up this part.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.02.14

Comment: The polytope being convex, every vertex is visible from every point of it. 

Comment: Indeed.  I am hoping that this will generalize to nonconvex polytopes.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.02.14

Comment: Very nice argument!

Comment: As you say, it might be a (much) harder problem to answer: "given P  and a line intersecting it at v (a vertex), find the subset of the the vertices of P which determines a facet containing the other intersection point"

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on how the point is given to you and what various operations cost you. If we assume that $x$ is given to you as a convex combination $x=\sum_1^N\lambda_ix_i$ with the $\lambda_i$ positive and adding to $1$ then one of the [standard proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)#Proof)s of the theorem reduces $N$ to $N-1$ and starts by finding a linear dependence among the quantities $x_j-x_i$ for $2 \le j \le N$ (unless $N \le n+1$ in which case you are done.) So this would entail solving systems of linear equations several times although not doing linear programming. If $N$ is only a bit larger than $n+1$ this might be reasonable.

Here is a rough idea for for $N$ much larger than $n+1$ and illustrated for $n=3$ which seems like it should work in general. The idea is to cut down the $x_i$ into a subset of about half the size which still contains $P$ in its convex hull.   Pick $n-1(=2)$ of the given points determining a flat $L$ of dimension $n-2$ (a line). Then the flats of dimension $n-1$ (planes) on $L$ give a linear order to the remaining $N-n+1$ points and $x$:  Pick a line $\ell$ on $x$ and let $y_i \in \ell$ be the point of intersection with the flat (plane) $E_i$ determined by $L$ and $x_i \notin L$. Now $x$ will fall between two of the $y_i$, say $y_1$ and $y_2$. Each of the flats $E_1$ and $E_2$ split $R^n$ into half spaces. Choose the plane which puts $x$ into a half space $H$ with no more than half of the $y_i.$ Then $H \cap P$ is a polytope with at most $\frac{N+n+1}2$ vertices which contains $x$ in its convex hull.

Comment: Usually "given a point" means "given the Cartesian coordinates of a point".

Comment:  "Given x in P" might reasonably be taken to mean that we have a linear combination proving that membership (which would also give the coordinates of x).  If the problem was "Given a set V of points and an extra point x , decide if x is in P, the convex hull of V, and if so find a subset of n+1 points..." then we might just have the coordinates.